# Python3 hashing gives different result

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha1, gnupg, hashlib

I try to calculate  sha1 for encrypted file (file.gpg) using Python3 code.

I test two func.

```py
import hashlib
import gnupg

def sha1sum(filename):
    h  = hashlib.sha1()
    b  = bytearray(128*1024)
    mv = memoryview(b)
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        for n in iter(lambda : f.readinto(mv), 0):
            h.update(mv[:n])
    return h.hexdigest()


def sha1_checksum(filename, block_size=65536):
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for block in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), b''):
            sha1.update(block)
    return sha1.hexdigest()

original = open('file.bin', 'rb')

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
encrypt = gpg.encrypt_file(original, 
                           recipients=None, 
                           passphrase=password,
                           symmetric='AES256', 
                           output=file)

sum = sha1sum(file)
sum = sha1_checksum(file)
```

First start of the script

```py
697cee13eb4c91f41922472d8768fad076c72166
697cee13eb4c91f41922472d8768fad076c72166
```

Second start of the script

```py
a95593f0d8ce274492862b58108a20700ecf9d2b
a95593f0d8ce274492862b58108a20700ecf9d2b
```

Does sha1sum() or sha1_checksum() wrong?

Or file encryption gives different file.gpg ?

Comment: where are `password` and `file` defined?

Comment: Additionally it may be worth reviewing this answer here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33752/will-encrypting-the-same-file-with-gnupg-and-the-same-key-produce-the-same-ciphe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem of Python, or even gpg.

The reason the hash changes is that `gpg` asymmetric encryption is *non-deterministic*, or so-called *probabilistic*.

Quote from [wiki page Probabilistic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption)

> Probabilistic encryption is the use of **randomness** in an encryption algorithm, so that when encrypting the same message several times it will, in general, **yield different ciphertexts**. The term "probabilistic encryption" is typically used in reference to **public key encryption algorithms**, however various symmetric key encryption algorithms achieve a similar property (e.g., block ciphers when used in a chaining mode such as CBC).